# Ruby on Rails SaaS Free Billing Management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway, saas, billing

I am making a Ruby on Rails app and I need to be able to bill users. I would like to use either PayPal, credit cards, or both. I looked at Saasy (https://github.com/maccman/saasy) but it requires one of three paid gateways, and I need a free gateway. Is there any way to do this for free?

Edit: Is it smart to do it on my own using the Railscasts PayPal tutorials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a free gateway.

The cheapest/best option in my opinion is run your site with [Recurly](http://recurly.com/) and use [Intuit Merchant Service](http://payments.intuit.com/products/internet-merchant-accounts.jsp) instead of PayPal.

Recurly has tight integration with IMS, and they also have a very nice [Gem](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-ruby) that you can add to your rails app which makes managing accounts and billing in-app quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use active_merchant
https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant